# Runnable goes in infinite loop in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I'm trying to develop a login activity in Android and I'm using the followind method for logging on:

```
private void attemptLogin() {
    /*if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }*/

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        RetrofitAPIService retrofitAPIService = RetrofitAPIService.aRetrofitApiService();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /*authService.login(email, password);*/
                UserAuthCommand userAuthCommand = new UserAuthCommand(email, password);
                UserProfile userProfile = retrofitAPIService.authorizeUser(userAuthCommand);
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (userProfile != null) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                };
                LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(runnable);
               /* final Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
                looper.quit();*/
            }
        }).start();
        //new UserLoginTask(email, password).execute((Void) null);
    }
}
```

I'm calling this method by hitting the sign in button, overriding setting setOnClickListener and overrinding onClick().

My problem is that when I enter some wrong credentials, the Toast is showing on the screen, but the backend goes into an infinite loop. I've made some debugging and it seems, that the current thread goes into loop() method from Looper.class.

Can anyone help me? Thx a lot!

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: Hello Marc, my problem was another thing. I've already fixed it and I'll put the solution for my problem here, later. Thx a lot anyway!

Comment: Great! You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use AsyncTask which manages threads and uithread callbacks automatically.

For example

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<ParamsType, ProgressType, ResultType> {
 protected ResultType doInBackground(ParamsType... params) {
     // This method runs in a background thread
     return result;
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(ResultType result) {
     // This method runs in UiThread
 }
}
```

Put your login logic in the `doInBackground()` method and the result logic inside `onPostExecute()`. And run it with:

```
new LoginTask().execute(params);
```

Hope this helps.